# Write a program that you give three strings inserted at the command line view the concatenation of the their initials

Tags: java

The goal is: "Write a program that you give three strings inserted and view the concatenation of the their initials."

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String prima = in.next();
String seconda = in.next();
String terza = in.next();

System.out.println(prima.charAt(0) + seconda.charAt(0) + terza.charAt(0));
```

Why does it print numbers and not the initials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `charAt` method returns a `char` primitive.  The rules around the `+` operator for a `char` primitive in Java say that it's treated as a number - basically it's converted to an `int` and then added.  This is the way Java was designed, and it's spelt out in [section 5.6.2 of the Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

The `+` operator only performs string concatenation when one of the operands is a `String`.  You can make this happen for your program if you change the last line as follows.

```
System.out.println("" + prima.charAt(0)+seconda.charAt(0)+terza.charAt(0));
```

That extra `""` is a `String`, so each `+` will then be adding a `String` to a `char`, in which case it concatenates, rather than converting the `char` values to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

These are three different ways to explore:

```
public class Answer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String prima = in.next();
        String seconda = in.next();
        String terza = in.next();

        //adding the primitive values
        System.out.println(prima.charAt(0) + seconda.charAt(0) + terza.charAt(0));

        //concat Strings
        System.out.println("" + prima.charAt(0) + seconda.charAt(0) + terza.charAt(0));

        //native print
        System.out.print(prima.charAt(0));
        System.out.print(seconda.charAt(0));
        System.out.print(terza.charAt(0));
        System.out.println();// new line

    }
}
```

With input like this: **asdf UIOP{ 123dd**
the output is:

```
231
aU1
aU1
```